# Typescript support for AMP in Next.js Custom App

Tags: typescript, next.js, amp-html

Using AMP in my custom Next.js using Typescript. According to the official Next.js documentation there's no support for Typescript although As a workaround you can manually create a file called amp.d.ts. My app has a src folder would this go inside my source folder or stay in root as a configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer the amp.d.ts will stay in root along with the other configuration files.